# I need to call a function in script defined in the component's HTML in the AngularJS on button click. How can I do this?

Tags: angularjs

```
<script>
   function myFunction() {
   console.log('YAY');
   alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
   }
</script>

<button type="button" ng-click="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

ng-click is not working in this case. Also how to call an unnamed JavaScript function on click?

Comment: where is the controller? "myFunction" must be declared in the controller scope

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to do that, like it's part of some library, you could do it by injecting $window service in your controller, then calling your controller function "myFunctionInController()"

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
   console.log('YAY');
   alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}</script>
<button type="button" ng-click="myFunctionInController()">Submit</button>
```

and from that function call my function

```
$window.myFunction()
```

Comment: getting this error: this.$window.myFunction is not a function

Answer (score 0):

myFunction should be declared inside the controller. Check simple [example](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_ng-click2)

```
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myFunction = () =>{
        console.log('YAY');
        alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
  }
});
</script>
```

The button should be inside controller Scope or Child or ng-controller directive

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <button type="button" ng-click="myFunction()">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: getting this error: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'myCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: can you share HTML and JS file.

Answer (score 0):

```
step 1: create a Module for html

var angularApp = angular.module('angularApp',[]);

step 2: create a Controller for View
angularApp.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

}]);

step 3: create html
<div class="main" ng-app="angularApp">
    <div class="Main" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">
        <button type="button" ng-click="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    </div>
<div>

step 4: add the Button click method in the Step 2 means in the Control

angularApp.controller('HomeCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.myFunction = function(){
        ("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
    }
}]);
```